# Align several rows according to vertical column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to have alignment so that purple rows will be the size of left column? Text inside of them would have various lengths. Currently they stack on top so there is a gap at bottom. I can position them somewhat with margins, but I was wondering if there is a better way? I am using Bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 white">
    <p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">

    <div class="row row-purple">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>lorem lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-purple">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>lorem ipsulorelorem ipsumm ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumm</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-purple">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>lorem ipslorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This layout can be easily achieved with flexbox. If that's an option let me know, or just update your question.

Comment: Do you have css we can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

Just add `display:flex` to the parent `row`.

I've added a little padding and margin to the demo to separate the elements.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.container > .row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1em;
}
.white {
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.row-purple {
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 white">
      <p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="row row-purple">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius laudantium quod possimus dolores, accusamus soluta deleniti illo ducimus maxime. Laborum, eum velit. Necessitatibus, tenetur, possimus?</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-purple">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta consequuntur veritatis a dolor eaque obcaecati, temporibus porro at repudiandae natus tempore aut asperiores, accusantium architecto fuga in odio reiciendis cupiditate libero iure,
            nemo unde! Quia unde, eum nihil dicta iure optio exercitationem, et sed praesentium nam harum reprehenderit, voluptatum accusantium. ipsulorelorem ipsumm ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumm</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-purple">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>lorem ipslorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumum</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MaPJBm)